# JSON is not deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net, azure-functions

Something is just wrong here and I can't figure it out.
I am POSTing to an Azure Function in Visual Studio 2019/c# in debug.  The POST looks like this:

[image]

In debug, the requestBody is grabbed from the stream and put into a string.  I am deserializing the JSON into an object (I've tried dynamic as well) but the object is not populated. In fact, the object "data" doesn't even seem to exist. See the image where I am at a breakpoint and the value "data" doesn't even exist:

[image]

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string requestBody = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
        {
            requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppInfo>(requestBody);
        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.UserGuid) ? "User not logged" : "User logged";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }

    public class AppInfo
    {
        public string AppName = "";
        public string UserGuid = "";
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your definition for `AppInfo` matches the incoming JSON, and please share the code, not screenshots of the code. Also include your definition for `AppInfo`.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Without the class definition for `AppInfo`, no one here can help - if it's not deserializing, it's likely because of conflict between the JSON definition of the object and the C# class definition.  And, as everyone else has said, you really need to include your code as text (not a pretty picture)

Comment: Actual mod here, [vandalising your posts isn't how you delete them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). Please refrain from continuing with this behavior when the post unlocks. if the system prevents you from deleting, there's not much you can do about it -- that said, I do believe you have a good question here, at least when it gets refined a little more. When it unlocks, an immediate action to take is to reduce the reliance your post has on images; this includes adding applicable errors as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't a code issue, but a problem with Visual Studio.
This was a part of a bigger project.  The other project I was going to send to release but decided to add some additional functionality.  I had changed the build to "release" and then added this code.  It wasn't able to run this code properly for whatever reason until I set the build type to "debug" - then the code started working properly.

Answer (score 2):

I am using below code I can get the Json deserialize object. Please check below

I tried with both **dynamic** and **Var** datatype to store the json deserialize object

```
public  static  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string requestBody = await  new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppInfo>(requestBody as  string);
    var val = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.UserGuid) ? "User not logged" : "User logged";
    return  new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}

public  class  AppInfo
{
    public  string AppName = "";
    public  string UserGuid = "";
}
```

[image]